# Oracle stored procedure to update and insert into child table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a table `Application` and scheduled task runs a stored procedure daily which checks for all the applications whose has expired and set their status to `Expired`.

I need to update that stored procedure so that against each application it updates, it also needs to create some child records to the actions table based upon the User Ids linked to the application.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> create some child records to the actions table

Looks like `INSERT INTO ACTIONS` as a `SELECT` which - in the `WHERE` clause - contains `USER_ID` linked to the application, does it not?

Comment: There are multiple user ids against each application and needs to create individual action record against each user id

Comment: OK, please, proceed to do so.

Comment: need to update the parent application table as well. my question is do I need to loop thru or using cursor etc or can this be done by creating sub procedures and calling them in the single select/update statement

Comment: Well, you can't call a procedure from SELECT (nor from UPDATE), so - you're now a step closer to choosing a way to do it. Is it a loop? Maybe, I don't know. Can you perform an update in a single statement? Can't tell either - if you can, it would probably perform better than a loop (as *row-by-row* will be *slow-by-slow*, which doesn't matter much if there are just a few rows to be updated).

Comment: 11;AB|22;CD|33;NN|44;BD|55;PP.
how can get 11;22;33;44;55 as individual rows from the above string